# Trying to reproduce the 'mobile-geolocation' script

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

**Trying to reproduce the 'mobile-geolocation' script from the Playwright site.
Getting this output:  [Imgur screenshot][1]
And here is my code:
[Paul's Nodejs repo][2]
[1]: https://imgur.com/a/bl6jS2q
[2]: https://github.com/paulgureghian/Nodejs_Programs/blob/master/Playwright/src/mobile_geolocation.js
I tried different 'text' strings, setup Google maps for my location, and even added a iphone11 emulated device in Chrome dev tools.**

Comment: Please add all relevant code, error messages, and screeshots directly here, not as links to other sites.

Comment: Selector `text=".widget-mylocation-button-icon"` doesn't look correct, nor the one shown in the error in the console. I recommend reading more about selectors.